# Opening strings as files in python

Tags: python

I've been struggling to open some files in python from a text file with a list of strings that are file names:
for example the .txt file would contain a list of names like the following
r'c:\users\computer\documents\example.txt'

I want to run a loop that looks at each line and sees if 'example' is in the line.
If so I want to open(line), however I cannot, and get a OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

If I manually type the file name in I can open it, but the variable will not open it.  I tried assigning a variable to line, replacing '\n'  trying StringIO, but getting nowhere.  I'm assuming its because python is looking at the variable as a string object and needs a file object.  But how do I make the string line into a file object of the same name.
Thanks

Comment: Post your code! have you removed the newline? `open(line.strip())` may work better. And is that .txt file holding literally `r'c:\users\computer\documents\example.txt'` or `c:\users\computer\documents\example.txt`

Comment: dates = ['2016q4', '2016q3', '2016q2', '2016q1']
for date in dates:
    with open('c:\\Users\Work Computer\My Documents\SUB_FILES.txt') as filelist2:
        for line in filelist2:
            if date in line:
                with open(line.strip()) as sub_file:
                    for line in sub_file:
                        split1 = line.split()
                        if line.startswith(cik):
                            Nl = line.split()
                            adsh.append(Nl[1])
                        else:
                            pass
    print(adsh)

Comment: dates = ['2016q4', '2016q3', '2016q2', '2016q1']
for date in dates:
    with open('c:\\Users\Work Computer\My Documents\SUB_FILES.txt') as filelist2:
        for line in filelist2:
            if date in line:
                with open(line.strip()) as sub_file:
                    for line in sub_file:
                        split1 = line.split()
                        if line.startswith(cik):
                            Nl = line.split()
                            adsh.append(Nl[1])
                        else:
                            pass
    print(adsh)

Comment: trying to post the code

Answer (score 0):

The `open` function accepts `str` arguments, so to do what you are describing you would do something like

```
with open(r'names.txt') as examples:
    for line in examples:
        if 'example' in line:
            with open(line.strip()) as example_file:
                # do something with example_file
```

So each `example_file` would be opened one-by-one based on the lines in `names.txt`.

Comment: I think that's `line.strip()`

Comment: still getting error.  the .txt file looks like this

Comment: r'C:\\Users\WorkComputer\Downloads\2016q4\sub.txt
r'C:\\Users\WorkComputer\Downloads\2016q3\sub.txt
r'C:\\Users\WorkComputer\Downloads\2016q2\sub.txt
r'C:\\Users\WorkComputer\Downloads\2016q1\sub.txt
r'C:\\Users\WorkComputer\Downloads\2015q4\sub.txt

Comment: Do the lines really contain `r'...`? Why the raw string prefix?

Comment: because usually when i open the file thats how i would type it

Comment: Try having the file content look like `C:\Users\WorkComputer\Downloads\2016q4\sub.txt` with no quotes and no `r` prefix. There is a big difference between how strings are represented and their actual content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as examples:
search = str(input('Who would you like to find?: '))
for line in examples:
    if search in line:
        print('Searching...')
        print(search, 'is here!')
```

Im still learning python myself but that should check every line for a name entered and print if found or not. And you can of course change to fit your needs. Let me know if this helped!!!